# How to get one or more dynamic field values in django method passing as dynamic parameter/arguments

Tags: python, php, django

I am new in django i am in stuck in getting dynamic field values from django method.
i understand php well.
in php i have made functions to pull one or more dynamic field data for my project purpose.
my php function is as belows:

```
function dynamicData($id,$table,$columns_to_get){
         include 'connect.php';//connection file
         $sel=$connect->query("SELECT $columns_to_get FROM $table WHERE id='$id'");
         $data=$sel->fetch_assoc();
         return $data;
         $connect->close();
         }
```

Now i can use above function like `$data=dynamicData(12,'users_table','name,id,age,gender');`
or
`$data=dynamicData(12,'users_table','name,gender');`

But in django i do not get such thought like above php function.
in django i make below function but i am in stuck

````
      ```
    def commonSingleFullNormal(identity,app,model,**kwargs):
        now_model=apps.get_model(app_label=app, model_name=model)
        data=now_model.objects.filter(identity=identity).values(**kwargs)

        return data[0]
      ```
````

It does not work why? Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not related to django, rather its related to python syntax. Regardless, if you rewrite your function like

```
def commonSingleFullNormal(identity, app, model, *args):
    now_model = apps.get_model(app_label=app, model_name=model)
    data = now_model.objects.filter(identity=identity).values(*args)
    return data[0]
```

Then, it should work with arbitrary number of arguments,
so both `commonSingleFullNormal(12, 'users', 'table', 'name', 'gender')` and `commonSingleFullNormal(12, 'users', 'table', 'name', 'id', 'age', 'gender')` will work